# Does HttpCalloutMock work when the tested method doesn't return HttpResponse?

Tags: unit-test, callout, httpcalloutmock

UPDATED: I've included the unit test.

I'm trying to test a Visualforce extension method that does a callout but returns a PageReference, not an HttpResponse.  I'm finding that the HttpCalloutMock doesn't give the expected result to the extension method.  In the code example below, the try is failing, even though I've set the mock to return a successful 201 code.

PS: I know the extension method is returning null for all situations, but there may be a scenario later  where I need to return a PageReference.

Mock interface:

```
// Mock callout for CreateProjectExtension testing.
@isTest
global class UnitTestMockHttp implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"apex":"test"}');
        // 201 is success code.
        res.setStatusCode(201);
        return res;
    }
}
```

VF extension:

```
public class CreateProjectExtension {
    public PageReference performCallout() {
        // code omitted.

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();

        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(Constants.PROCORE_ENDPOINT);
        req.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        req.setBody(params);
        System.debug('*** req: ' + req.getBody());

        try {
            resp = http.send(req);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Fatal, 
                    resp.getStatusCode() + ':' + ex.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }

        if (resp != null && resp.getStatusCode() == 201) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, 'Project was created.'));
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 
                resp.getStatusCode() + ':' + resp.getStatus()));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
static testmethod void testCreateProjectExtension() {
    Account acct = new Account(Name = 'Apex Test');
    insert acct;

    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Apex Test', StageName = 'Closed Won', 
            RecordTypeId = GeneralHelper.recTypesMap.get('Opportunity_new_customer'), 
            CloseDate = date.today().addMonths(1), Type = 'New Annual Access', 
            Service_Level_Agreement__c = 'Foundation Account', Amount = 100);
    opp = UnitTestData.fillOppFields(opp);
    insert opp;

    Test.startTest();
    PageReference pg = Page.CreateProject;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pg);
    pg.getParameters().put('id', opp.Id);

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(opp);
    CreateProjectExtension ext = new CreateProjectExtension(sc);

    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new UnitTestMockHttp());
    ext.performCallout();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Don't specify any return type other than void until you need to. It will lead to code bloat and make maintenance more tedious later. The same can be said of unused parameters.

Comment: Can you send your test class code? Hope you are using Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new UnitTestMockHttp()); before calling the method.

Comment: use a constructor with arguments for UnitTestMockHttp so the testmethod can tell the mock what kind of error (if any) to generate so you can test your error handling logic; e.g. `new UnitTestMockHttp(String responseCode) {this.responseCode = responseCode;}` -- then your respond() method can dynamically set the response code based on the testsetup

Comment: @crop1645 thanks for the suggestion about the parameter

Comment: np - always nice to see someone who wants to thoroughly test callout error handling via testmethods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the return type of the function is, or even if there is any return type (i.e. it is void), so that's definitely not the problem. Please note that if you're getting an exception, there is no status code; the response object from your method wouldn't be returned. Most likely, you haven't called `Test.setMock`, thus causing an exception, which is why you're not seeing the response you expect. Also, specifically, you're only *not* getting a NullPointerException because you're creating an empty response object in your variable, which is probably why you're confused.

Comment: thanks as always for your responses.  But you mean Test.setMock(), right?  I couldn't find any callMock() method.  I've posted the unit test.

Comment: You're right. Test.setMock. I'll look at your code and update.